# How to call partial view using ajax method from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I work with `asp.net` and I have some issues.

I created partial view with error message and I want to call view using `jQuery`.

I have already created `function` in `controller` which returns a partial view. But I am stuck with ajax, all time I get errors.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadPartialView()
{
    return PartialView("_ErrorMessageWindow");
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action('LoadPartialView'))",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
      }
});
```

**Error:**

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 GET https://localhost:5001/@(Url.Action('LoadPartialView'))?_=1565937416181 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There's typo error in `Url.Actio`. Correct it.

Comment: @RahulNikate thanks, fixed, but got same error

Comment: Where you are writing your `Jquery` code? Is it in the `.cshtml` or separate `.js` file.

Comment: @RahulNikate in **.js** file, **Partial view created in cshtml**

Comment: Please see my answer for your error. Thank you @qunzor. Also let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Please accept answer if answer helped you. So by that you will give credit to user who have posted answer for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for not working:**

`@Url.Action()` is Razor server side code and that will not be parsed in external `.js` files.

**Solution:**

**Create this `<div>` in your `.cshtml`:**

`<div id="partial-view-url" data-request-url="@Url.Action("LoadPartialView", "ControllerName")"></div>`

**then get Partial View Url in your separate/external `.js` file using `data-request-url` like below:**

```
$("#partial-view-url").data('data-request-url');
```

**So your `$.Ajax` will become like this:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: $("#partial-view-url").data('data-request-url'),
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (data) {

        }
});
```

**Another way is to declare global variable:**
Create global variable in your main `.cshtml` file and use it in your external `.js` file.

```
//Declare this variable in your main `.cshtml` file.
var partial-view-url = @Url.Action("LoadPartialView","ControllerName");

//and then use it in your separate/external `.js` file.
$.ajax({
        url: partial-view-url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (data) {

        }
});
```